# VS Code: Plugin to automatically close scss declarations and add comments referring to selector

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a plugin that will automatically close brackets and put a comment like this :

```
.my-class{
    css code
} // /.my-class
```

or

```
label{
    code
}// /label
```

Is it possible to find something like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
You can also access this page by clicking the (?) at the top right of the page, then "Help Center", then it's the first link of the summary at the top left.

Comment: I don't understand your answer ? What do you mean ?

Comment: (4) "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" I just don't want to report your question as off-topic, but I think you should close your question and re-open it on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for this

Comment: You could do that with snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your snippets file:

```
"cssComment": {
  "prefix": "css//",
  "body": [
    "$1 {",
      "\t$2",
      "} /* $1 */"
  ],
  "description": "add comment to end of css entry"
},
```

1. `css//` <kbd>TAB</kbd>
2. type `.my-class` <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>
3. Result:

   ```
   .my-class {
      [cursor here]
   } /* .my-class */
   ```